# Friendfeed schemaless data in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, friendfeed

I read an article around schema-less database which sounds cool. (http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql)

But what isn't clear to me is how do they run search queries on this data? Since the data is in JSON format how do we look for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're using [sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) for that

Comment: Can't see that anywhere, how do you know that?

Answer (score 2):

For attributes that are needed for filtering / searching, they are first indexed using a separate table. This makes the data more transparent.

Let me quote what this post says: http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql

> Indexes are stored in separate tables. To create a new index, we create a new table storing the attributes we want to index on all of our database shards.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine they have a separate search engine with its own index - probably not even in MySQL, something like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).